# Attempt to predict new data resulting in ValueError despite successfully trained and tested model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is to see the next day prediction for bitcoin price, based on my regression model. I don't believe the cause for the error lies in my raw data, as it contains no values that meet the description of NaN, infinity or too large. I'm able to build and evaluate the model in training and test segments of the data. My suspicion is I am using the language incorrectly and am not telling the predict function to predict what I think I am here vs earlier in the code.

Here are the relevant portions leading up to this error, I'm using a DecisionTreeRegressor from sklearn and have left out feature selection,

```
#Import libraries and Data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import talib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\BTC.csv')
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#name open, high, low, close and volume data from csv 

BTC = dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\BTC.csv')


#Convert Data from Int to Float

BTC.Volume = BTC.Volume.astype(float)
BTC.High = BTC.High.astype(float)
BTC.Low = BTC.Low.astype(float)
BTC.Close = BTC.Close.astype(float)

#Create forward looking columns using shift

BTC['NextDayPrice'] = BTC['Close'].shift(-1)

#Copy dataframe and clean data (remove data consumed by lagging Indicators)

BTC_cleanData = BTC.copy()
BTC_cleanData.dropna(inplace=True)

#Split Data into Training and Testing Set
#separate the features and targets into separate datasets.
#split the data into training and testing sets using a 70/30 split 
#Using splicing, we will separate the features from the target into individual data sets.  
X_all = BTC_cleanData.iloc[:, BTC_cleanData.columns != 'NextDayPrice']  # feature values for all days
y_all = BTC_cleanData['NextDayPrice']  # corresponding targets/labels
print (X_all.head())  # print the first 5 rows
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Split the data into training and testing sets using the given feature as the target
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

#Create a decision tree regressor and fit it to the training set
regressor = LinearRegression()

regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)

print ("Training set: {} samples".format(X_train.shape[0]))
print ("Test set: {} samples".format(X_test.shape[0]))

#Evaluate Model (in-sample Accuracy and Mean Squared Error)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

scores = cross_val_score(regressor, X_test, y_test, cv=10)
print ("accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() / 2))    

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, regressor.predict(X_test))
print("MSE: %.4f" % mse)

#Predict Next Day Price

X=BTC[-1:]
print(regressor.predict(X))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-d171bb7e543f> in <module>
      2 
      3 X=BTC[-1:]
----> 4 print(regressor.predict(X))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    223             Returns predicted values.
    224         """
--> 225         return self._decision_function(X)
    226 
    227     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    205         check_is_fitted(self)
    206 
--> 207         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    208         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
    209                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    576         if force_all_finite:
    577             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 578                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    579 
    580     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     58                     msg_err.format
     59                     (type_err,
---> 60                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
     61             )
     62     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Thanks in advance for any insight or help you can give in solving this.

Comment: In any case, `X[-1:]` contains a single element - please post it here, otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: The element is what I am trying to predict, so it's NaN. I had assumed that should be the case but I must be wrong, in what way should I define the new data input for predict() to not get a NaN error?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `X` contains `NaN`.

Drop null value from X and make prediction as follows.

```
print(regressor.predict(X.dropna()))
```

Comment: I got: 
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 146)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
By defining X as BTC[-1:], I was trying to define the new data, so shouldn't that be NaN until predicted?  Sorry if this is very basic, I'm a total beginner.